# How to iterate trough an object and it's nested array to get Key and All corresponding Values in Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a json file containing following data. Objects Containing two keys City and Societies inside city. I am trying to iterate through array to get list of Cities and all societies inside specific city.
I am able to loop through objects but how about iteration on Nested Array inside cities object.
I need result in below format

City: Islamabad
Socities:
Zaraj
River Garden
Soan Garden
CBR Town
PWD Society
Pakistan Town

```
{
  cities: [
    {
      City: "Islamabad",
      Societies: [
        "Zaraj",
        "River Garden",
        "Soan Garden",
        "CBR Town",
        "PWD Society",
        "Pakistan Town",
      ],
    },
    {
      City: "Lahore",
      Societies: [
        "Lahore Smart City",
        "Bahria Town Lahore",
        "Gulberg Lahore",
        "Gulshan-e-Lahore",
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: The OP should provide the source data (e.g. the data-structure of the json) and the expected final data structure as code. How the Q. is currently presented, one only could guess from the description that one does not look at the source data code but rather at the expected result.

Comment: From how the source data gets described by words, does the source structure look similar to ... `{"Islamabad": ["Zaraj", "River Garden" /* ,.. */], "Lahore": ["Lahore Smart City" /* ,.. */]}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would start by renaming the keys in the object so that we have the following `data` to work with:

```js
const data = {
  cities: [
    {
      name: "Islamabad",
      societies: [
        "Zaraj",
        "River Garden",
        "Soan Garden",
        "CBR Town",
        "PWD Society",
        "Pakistan Town"
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Lahore",
      societies: [
        "Lahore Smart City",
        "Bahria Town Lahore",
        "Gulberg Lahore",
        "Gulshan-e-Lahore"
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Then this will do the job:

```js
data.cities.map(city=> {
    return `The city ${city.name} has the following societies: ${city.societies.join(' ')}`;
});
```

We now have the following array we can use where applicable:

```js
[
    "The city Islamabad has the following societies: Zaraj River Garden Soan Garden CBR Town PWD Society Pakistan Town",
    "The city Lahore has the following societies: Lahore Smart City Bahria Town Lahore Gulberg Lahore Gulshan-e-Lahore"
]
```